# PL/SQL function compilation errors in f_chkPrime code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL, here my code function to find prime number or not..

```
create or replace function f_chkPrime(v number)
return varchar2
declare number check;
as begin
for i 2..v loop
   if mod(v,i)=0
   then  
       check:=0;
      exit;
   else
         check:=1;
      end if;
      end loop;
 if(check=1)
  then  
       return 'prime';
   else
       return 'not prime';
    end if;
     end f_chkPrime;
   /
```

I am getting compilation error in sql plus. Where I am getting wrong?

Comment: I am using oracle SQL/Plus,it just say function created with compilation error.

Comment: PLS-0103 Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Yeah, so looks like Justin is right (as usual) ;) lol ... also, please include the entire error message in future - it would have mentioned a line # ;) that can help us pinpoint the error in some cases ..

Comment: @Codder please update the question with the complete details about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As [Justin Cave noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685982/1509264), you don't use a `DECLARE` statement for a function.
- The `FOR` loop is missing an `IN` statement.
- You check too many numbers as: you will never get a prime factor of `v` that is greater than `SQRT(v)`; and you do not need to check all the even numbers if you have checked that it is not a multiple of 2.
- You check if `MOD(v,v)=0` (which will always be true) and so the function will always return `not prime`.
- You don't need to `EXIT` the loop; instead you can return the outcome as soon as you find it.

Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_chkPrime(
  v NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  np CONSTANT CHAR(9) := 'Not Prime';
  p  CONSTANT CHAR(5) := 'Prime';
BEGIN
  IF v = 2 THEN
    RETURN p;
  ELSIF v <= 1 OR MOD(v,2) = 0 THEN
    RETURN np;
  END IF;
  FOR i IN 1 .. (SQRT(v)-1)/2 LOOP
    IF MOD(v,i*2+1) = 0 THEN
      RETURN np;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN p;
END f_chkPrime;
/
```

**Testing**

```
SELECT LEVEL AS Value,
       f_chkPrime( LEVEL ) AS is_prime
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30;
```

**Results**

```
     VALUE IS_PRIME
---------- ---------
         1 Not Prime 
         2 Prime     
         3 Prime     
         4 Not Prime 
         5 Prime     
         6 Not Prime 
         7 Prime     
         8 Not Prime 
         9 Not Prime 
        10 Not Prime 
        11 Prime     
        12 Not Prime 
        13 Prime     
        14 Not Prime 
        15 Not Prime 
        16 Not Prime 
        17 Prime     
        18 Not Prime 
        19 Prime     
        20 Not Prime 
        21 Not Prime 
        22 Not Prime 
        23 Prime     
        24 Not Prime 
        25 Not Prime 
        26 Not Prime 
        27 Not Prime 
        28 Not Prime 
        29 Prime     
        30 Not Prime
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always helpful to include the actual error message so that we don't have to guess.  My assumption is that the error is that you have a `declare` that you don't want.  You use `declare ... begin ... end` to create anonymous PL/SQL blocks.  In a function, you'd declare your variables between the `as|is` and the `begin`.  The variable name also comes before the data type not before.

```
create or replace function f_chkPrime(v number)
return varchar2
as
  check number;
begin
  for i 2..v loop
    if mod(v,i)=0
    then  
       check:=0;
      exit;
    else
      check:=1;
    end if;
  end loop;

  if(check=1)
  then  
     return 'prime';
  else
     return 'not prime';
  end if;
end f_chkPrime;
```